# Django 1.5 feed RSS not validating?

Tags: django, rss

I am using default django 1.5 feed app to generate an RSS feed. The code is similar to the exemple in the django documentation.
But if i try to validate the code in the w3c validator i got this [error](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/SelfDoesntMatchLocation.html). Why? Is it a bug in django?